# Sending a static text in ajax

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I'm making an image reload page

```html
<button id="ref_qo" class="button_ref"><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none !important;">Reload question</a></button>
```

But this is not done correctly

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ref_qo').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({

type: "GET",
url: 'image_lod.php',
data: { id: 'image_url', IdCompanyAnbar: '12'},

success: function(response){
var resp = JSON.parse(response);

if (resp.success == "0"){
alert(resp.message)
} else {
alert(resp.message);
}
}
});
});
});
</script>
```

and gives the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
> at JSON.parse ()
> at Object.success ((index):334:24)
> at i (jquery.min.js:2:28017)
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2:28783)
> at A (jquery.min.js:4:14035)
> at XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4:16323)

I don't think there is a problem with the server

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['image_url']) {

$url = $_GET['image_url'];
    // Save all user data
if($url == 12){
echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'message' => 'Please complete both fields'));
} else {
echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
}
}
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: anchor inside a button or vice-versa is an invalid Markup. One can not be a child of another. An anchor is for redirecting to another resource while a button solely is used as a trigger to fire a script. If you need both add an onclick-trigger/eventListener to the anchor or a `location.href`-command to the script of the button.

Comment: Seems like the server is not responding with JSON but HTML, considering the first character is `<`. Are you setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proble: in this condition if (isset($_GET['image_url']) {....

1: you didn't send the image_url to the server.

2: and missing the ) in the if condition.

You can modify the code on the server as follows

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']=='image_url') {
     $url = $_GET['IdCompanyAnbar']??0;
     // Save all user data
     if($url == 12){
         echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'message' => 'Please complete both fields'));
     } else {
         echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
     }
}else{
         echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
}
?>
```

Comment: Now it gives this error on the page

"Please complete both fields"

Comment: @alimosavy          echo json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'message' => 'Please complete both fields'));
Please change the result returned at this command line